# Objective-c: NSPasteboard: what's difference with - setData:forType:, - setString:forType: and - setPropertyList:forType:

Tags: c++, objective-c, segmentation-fault, objective-c++, nspasteboard

i want to know what's difference with - setData:forType: - setPropertyList:forType: and - setString:forType: in NSPasteboard api?
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspasteboard?language=objc

when i notice the description of setPropertyList and setString: `This method invokes setData:forType: to perform the write.`

and when I write String content to pasteboard, I have to use setString and can't use setData. If i use setData, there will be an exception:

`*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Calling -setData:forType: on NSPasteboard or NSPasteboardItem with object of type __NSSetM instead of NSData.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
        0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffcd4a92cb __exceptionPreprocess + 171
        1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffe22da48d objc_exception_throw + 48
        2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffcd527c3d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
        3   AppKit                              0x00007fffcb1af86d -[NSPasteboard _setData:forType:index:usesPboardTypes:] + 287
        4   libclipboard.so                     0x000000010b36b9ea _ZN5cclib9ccsys_api12ClipboardMac16setClipboardDataEPNS0_13ClipboardDataE + 394`

And there is another more serious bug, when i try to set a file to the pasteboard, i use setData method. and will also receive the same exception.

Is there any example to set all pasteboard type to pasteboard?

my code in github: https://github.com/hello-chenchen/cc-clipboard/blob/master/src/clipboard_mac.mm
https://github.com/hello-chenchen/cc-clipboard/blob/master/test/test_mac.mm

the code segment:

```
int ClipboardMac::setClipboardData(ClipboardData* data){
        //FIXED: fix setString failed error
        [pasteboard clearContents]

        if(EN_CB_FILES == data->type) {
            id buffer = (id)data->bufferData;
            cout << "setClipboardData: NSFilenamesPboardType" << endl;
            //ERROR: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Could not write property list with invalid format to the pasteboard.  The object contains non-property list types: __NSSetM'
            return [pasteboard setPropertyList:buffer forType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
        } else if(EN_CB_TEXT == data->type) {
            NSString* buffer = (NSString*)data->bufferData;
            cout << "setClipboardData: NSStringPboardType" << endl;
            return [pasteboard setString:buffer forType:NSStringPboardType];
        } else {
            cout << "setClipboardData: NSRTFDPboardType" << endl;
            return CC_INVALID;
        }
    }
```

the full error log:
https://github.com/hello-chenchen/cc-clipboard/blob/master/log/error.log

i don't know if i need to malloc the full length of the buffer which i get from the pasteboard by call dataForType method. because when i copy a file type, the buffer is always the same in size(i forget about the read size, maybe 148?).

for the full code:https://github.com/hello-chenchen/cc-clipboard

i am so confused, thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the class of `buffer` at runtime?

Comment: NSData, NSString or id. there are some code segment below

Comment: `NSData* cbData = [pasteboard dataForType:type];
NSString* strData = [pasteboard stringForType:type];
id fileData = [pasteboard propertyListForType:type];`

Comment: `int ClipboardMac::convertClipboardData(NSData* data, id fileData, NSString* strData, NSString* type, NSString* name) {
/** code **/
if([NSFilenamesPboardType isEqualToString:type]) {
    cout << "convertClipboardData: NSFilenamesPboardType" << endl;
    clipboardData.type = EN_CB_FILES;
    clipboardData.bufferData = data;
} else if([NSStringPboardType isEqualToString:type]) {
    cout << "convertClipboardData: NSStringPboardType" << endl;
    clipboardData.type = EN_CB_TEXT;
    clipboardData.bufferData = strData;
}
/** code **/
}`

Comment: Post the code in the question please.

Comment: What is the actual class of `buffer` at runtime, what is `[buffer class]`? Is it possible to reproduce the issue in a small test project? What is your code supposed to do?